# How to link NumPy to Eigen3, or OpenBLAS, GotoBLAS2, ATLAS?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I installed Anaconda3(with Python3.7), and found that the NumPy extension is linked MKL via `numpy.__config__.show()`:

```
mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Anaconda\\Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/Anaconda\\Library\\include']
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Anaconda\\Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/Anaconda\\Library\\include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Anaconda\\Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/Anaconda\\Library\\include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Anaconda\\Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/Anaconda\\Library\\include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt']
    library_dirs = ['C:/Anaconda\\Library\\lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/Anaconda\\Library\\include']
```

In terms of that I use Ryzen CPU, so I want that my NumPy is linked to Eigen3, or OpenBLAS, GotoBLAS2, ATLAS? Which conda commands can help me get it?

Comment: What about `conda install -c conda-forge openblas`? Perhaps, following `conda install -c conda-forge numpy`?

Comment: And https://conda-forge.org/docs/blas.html

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Thanks for your comment, I have tried this way, however it cannot change NumPy itself. NumPy is still linked to MKL.

Answer (score 0):

First query a list of available numpy builds on the conda-forge channel with:

```
conda search -c conda-forge numpy
```

Look in the list for a numpy build that has `openblas` in its build version. Then install that version with the `conda install` command. For example:

```
conda install -c conda-forge numpy=1.15.4=py37_blas_openblash442142e_1000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, it got wrong with    
 ```Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - keras-preprocessing -> keras[version='>=2.1.6'] -> scipy[version='>=0.14'] -> blas=[build=mkl]
  - numpy==1.15.4=py36_blas_openblash442142e_1000
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.```

Comment: After I posted this question, I have installed TensorFlow extension, and it changed my Python version from 3.7 to 3.6 automatically....